# UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate Will End Preview?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, mobile

I have a UIDocumentInteractionController that is being used to display full screen previews within my application.  This is all working, the issue I am having is regarding orientation changes when the full screen viewer is open.

If the viewer is open and the interface orientation changes I need to manually update views in my stack.

I currently have this coded into the method:

`- (void)documentInteractionControllerDidEndPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller`

This is working as expected but it causes a slight jump as the view is redrawn (the view is now visible).

Does anyone know any way I can hook into an event that would be called just before the Interaction Controller Preview ends - something like: `documentInteractionControllerWillEndPreview`

Is there an NSNotification or event I could hook into to catch this?

Thanks

Ross

Comment: sorry @atreat I didn't find a solution to this problem